# Send-MailMessage multiple recipient from CSV file recipient

Tags: powershell, csv, email

I don't know what I am missing here. I have a csv with multiple email address in multiple rows under column Email_Address. The csv file may have the same email address duplicated or may have multiple email address.

```
Email_Address
a@gmail.com
b@hotmail.com
c@aol.com
d@yahoo.com
b@hotmail.com
```

I have written a function to email at one shot to all the recipient in the To List. Not sure why I am getting error even though I have formatted based on the Send-MailMessage format

```
Function EmailNotification ([string]$ToEmail, [string]$LogFileToAttach, [string]$Change){
    $emailServer = "mailhosts.svc.net"
    $emailFrom = "NoReply-Feedback <no-reply@feedback.com>"
    $emailSubject = "Feedback from Automated Window - $Change"
    $emailBody = "Hello <br> <p>Please find the feedback from Automated Email notification for the Change you have raised. </p> <p>Do not Respond. On Issue reach out for help.  </p> <p>Regards</p> <p>Automated Window</p>"
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $emailServer `
                     -From $emailFrom `
                     -To $ToEmail `
                     -Subject $emailSubject `
                     -Body $emailBody `
                     -Attachments $LogFileToAttach `
                     -Priority Low `
                     -DeliveryNotificationOption None `
                     -BodyAsHTML

}
```

I am reading a csv file and trying to capture all the email address

```
$emailToArray = "'" + ( (@($CSVfile.Email_Address) | Get-Unique) -join "', '" ) + "'"
```

I am calling the function passing the $emailToArray

```
EmailNotification $emailToArray $($ChangeLogFile) $($ChangeLogFile).Split("_")[3]
```

I can see the $emailToArray contains 'a@gmail.com', 'b@hotmail.com', '...' etc when echo displaying from within the function which I guess is the right format for To field in Send-MailMessage. But I am getting the following errors when it has multiple email address to process in the file:(

```
Send-MailMessage : Syntax error in parameters or arguments. The server response was: 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax
At D:\Change\PutChange.ps1:29 char:5
+     Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $emailServer `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Any direction will be helpful

Comment: In the function's parameter list, change `[string]$ToEmail` to `[string[]]$ToEmail`.

Comment: Changed to Function EmailNotification ([string[]]$ToEmail, [string]$LogFileToAttach, [string]$Change). Still getting same error

Comment: Pass `$CSVfile.Email_Address` directly, don't try to construct an array - it's _already an array_

Comment: :) it worked Thank You very much. This is what happens when you grow old. Thank You mate